# why we should use neural network in detecting objects like detecting license plates

Tags: machine-learning, python

Am learning some techniques to be able to detect license plate accurately But I saw some recent researches talk about DEEP learning or Neural network (NN) for reaching best results. do I should use it for detecting the plates accurately, I need just advice to start working in the right away? .I implement some methods to detect object using python and OpenCV 3.1.16 and test my code on California plates it gave me some good results, but when I rotate them a bit for 5 degrees or 10 some My system gave me poor results.

if I should use NN
- is the training dataset just cropped plates ? or some characters images 
- if the images have rotation means I should wide my training data set

after that, if for example need to extract the plate took each cropped plate and search for it in the image ?

Comment: Try image augmentation like random rotations  etc.

Comment: yes I used it for rotations but my questions what is best to train my program for detecting license plates . is to take all possible linces plates or take each font with diffrent roations

Answer (score 2):

Neural networks aren't magical, they're incredibly sensitive to the data that you use to train them -- just like every other model. If the problem you're trying to solve has license plates that are rotated a bit, then you'll need to model that as a part of the task. This is called data augmentation, and it's used all over the place in machine learning and especially machine learning for image-related tasks.

What you should use as training data likewise depends on your application. Will your model receive a picture of a car, from which something will have to identify and extract the patch of pixels containing the license plate? Or are images of license plates available already, and all you have to do is read off the digits?

Comment: I've already the images which it contains cars with different license plates
some of these images in the night and some have some rotations https://prnt.sc/or94fj & https://prnt.sc/or94sw

Answer (score 0):

The answer and comments above basically nail it. Here are a couple comments to add a couple thoughts.

Any machine learning algorithm will be sensitive to changes in the data (or the task at hand). From a matrix perspective, if it expects for example the first ten columns to represent the left side of the license plat, and now you rotate the plate, those first 10 columns now might represent the "top" or the "bottom" of the license plate... so it wouldn't be fair to say NNs/DL are not good, since you're evaluating them using a moving target. So better to train a model for the task it will be used on, rather than hypothetical variants. If you will be expecting rotations as inputs, then that should be part of your training of the model, otherwise, maybe not as useful.

The reason why NNs and DL tend to be powerful is they have the ability to extract the signal and summarize complex, local relationships between features in an image via built-in functionality in their architecture (e.g., convolution layers or auto-encoders). That does not mean that they're bullet-proof, but for image-recognition tasks they offer probably the most powerful toolkit for it at the expense of computation time, understanding how to design and optimize their architecture, etc..

Hope this helps!

Comment: For example (license plate detection )if I want to train my program using python. i need to crop each image i took then save it or i need to crop each character from the plate then save it or i just need to detect the character font then save it and to handle the rotation also  ive to rotate the croped plates or the croped fonts